# How to move the folder from home directory to the root directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, root, home-directory

I copied one folder from local to home directory by using WINSCP.

Now I want to move the folder from home directory into root directory.

I used this command:

```
  mv /home/user/data/* /root/data
```

It throws Permission Denied Error

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.  Try https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have root privileges. In case you have root password, you can try using sudo:

```
sudo mv /home/user/data/* /root/data
```